# I don't know where to start...

Tags: reference-request

So I am studying mathematical analysis of continuity and suits and I don't get how proofs are being made or how the answer should be put... I need some guidance. So if you can   tell me about a book that teaches basic mathmatical analysis that would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Suits"? What is that? Are you studying by your own or at some university?

Comment: The common recommendation for a serious introduction is Rudin's $\textit{Principles of Mathematical Analysis}$

Comment: @DonAntonio "suits" (from French) are "sequences".

Comment: @user376343 O, oui monsieur. Thanks (mercy beaucoup)